# VB.Net Box Plot Series Labels

Tags: vb.net

The following code creates a simple boxplot in VB.net. However, I cannot figure out how to change the x axis labels. Currently they are 1 and 2 but I need them to be text values. I also want all of the numeric lables removed:

[image: Format]

```
    Dim yVal As Double() = {55.62, 45.54, 73.45, 9.73, 88.42, 45.9, 63.6, 85.1, 67.2, 23.6}
    Dim yVal2 As Double() = {35.62, 25.54, 43.45, 23.73, 43.42, 12.9, 23.6, 65.1, 54.2, 41.6}

    Chart1.Series.Clear()
    Chart1.Series.Add("BoxPlotSeries")

    Chart1.Series.Add("1")
    Chart1.Series("1").Points.DataBindY(yVal)

    Chart1.Series.Add("2")
    Chart1.Series("2").Points.DataBindY(yVal2)

    Chart1.Series("1").Enabled = False
    Chart1.Series("2").Enabled = False

    Chart1.Series("BoxPlotSeries").ChartType = SeriesChartType.BoxPlot
    Chart1.Series("BoxPlotSeries")("BoxPlotSeries") = "1;2"

    Chart1.Series("BoxPlotSeries")("BoxPlotWhiskerPercentile") = "15"
    Chart1.Series("BoxPlotSeries")("BoxPlotShowAverage") = "true"
    Chart1.Series("BoxPlotSeries")("BoxPlotShowMedian") = "true"
    Chart1.Series("BoxPlotSeries")("BoxPlotShowUnusualValues") = "true"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add custom labels to a new ChartArea1, and then link the  BoxPlotSeries to the ChartArea1 so that the axis can be controlled.   There's actually more than this and I have added what will make it work.  I am also including 2-point decimal precision ("N2") in the Y-axis value, which you can change to integer via using "= N0".   I would also turn off both vertical and horizontal grids, since they look horrendous in mathematical plots.  Place all the code below after your code:

```
'Create new chart area called "ChartArea1", link BoxPlotSeries to it
Dim ChartArea1 As New ChartArea
ChartArea1.Name = "ChartArea1"
Chart1.ChartAreas.Add(ChartArea1)
Chart1.Series("BoxPlotSeries").ChartArea = "ChartArea1"

'Add the custom labels "One" and "Two" to the X-axis
Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.CustomLabels.Add((1) * 2D, 0.0, "One")
Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.CustomLabels.Add((2) * 2D, 0.0, "Two")

'X-Axis
Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = False
Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.IntervalAutoMode = False 
Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.MajorTickMark.LineWidth = 3
Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = -90
Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = True
Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible = True
Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.IsMarginVisible = True

'Y-Axis
Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = False
Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "N2"
Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.LabelStyle.Angle = 0
Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.IntervalAutoMode = True 
Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.MajorTickMark.LineWidth = 3
```

Comment: Thank you! This was an old post that never got answered - much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks!  One thing I observed is that I had to comment out the line: `Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = True`
to get the angle to rotate to -90 with the command:
`Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = -90`